# Why isn't my "Calculate Course Grade" button working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This code is supposed to calculate a grade when one enters numbers into the text boxes. When the "Calculate Course Grade" button is clicked, it does nothing. When troubleshooting the code, I was given two separate errors:
The first error states that "document.getElementbyId" is not a valid function.
The second error states "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."
I am relatively new to coding, so if you could explain what those errors mean and how to possibly help, that would be great!

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Lab 4 Grade Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Grade Calculation </h2>
<p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value=""><br><br>
Homework average: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" value=""><br><br>
Lab average: <input type="text" id="labsBox" value=""><br><br>
Midterm score: <input type="text" id="midtermBox" value=""><br><br>
Final Exam score: <input type="text" id="examBox" value="">
</p>
<br>
<!-- Start input button -->
<input type="button" value="Calculate Course Grade"
onclick="homework=parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('homeworkBox').value);
labs=parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('labsBox').value);

midterm=parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('midtermBox').value);

finalExam=parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('examBox').value);

overall_Average = homework*0.25 + labs*0.20 + midterm*0.25 + finalExam*0.30;

document.getElementbyId('outputDiv').innerHTML=

'Hello '+ document.getElementbyId('nameBox').value+', your overall course average grade is: '+ overall_Average;">

<!-- Close input button -->
<hr>
<br><br>  
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo- getElementById. Note the capital B.

Comment: Putting tons of lines in `onclick` is very bad practice; use a `<script>` with a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was an typo. Its 'getElementByID'. Also Avoid writing large codes inside onclick.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Lab 4 Grade Calculator </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> Grade Calculation </h2>
    <p>
        Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size=12 value=""><br><br>
        Homework average: <input type="text" id="homeworkBox" value=""><br><br>
        Lab average: <input type="text" id="labsBox" value=""><br><br>
        Midterm score: <input type="text" id="midtermBox" value=""><br><br>
        Final Exam score: <input type="text" id="examBox" value="">
    </p>
    <br>
    <!-- Start input button -->
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Course Grade" onclick="grade()">

    <!-- Close input button -->
    <hr>
    <br><br>
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function grade() {
        homework = parseFloat(document.getElementById('homeworkBox').value);
        labs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('labsBox').value);

        midterm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('midtermBox').value);

        finalExam = parseFloat(document.getElementById('examBox').value);

        overall_Average = homework * 0.25 + labs * 0.20 + midterm * 0.25 + finalExam * 0.30;

        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
            'Hello ' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + ', your overall course average grade is: ' +
            overall_Average;
    }
</script>

</html>
```